# Would non-visible light be deflected the same way than visible light by a lens?

Tags: visible-light

My lessons about optics are long behind me, so I need to confirm a point:

**Are IR and UV affected the same way as visible spectrum by a lens?**

Let's say someone is able to perceive the full light spectrum. If he is looking through a pair of binoculars, does the effect apply to IR and UV as well?

Edit: I'm curious as whether common glass lens affect similarly all the light, or just visible spectrum.

Comment: depends on the lens material and whether it refracts your particular wavelength of light. Calcium fluoride is better for UV than glass.

Comment: Ok, so ill posed question. How is light affected by a lens of plain, mundane glass? Does it only work properly for visible light, or does the property affect IR and UV as well?

Comment: well consider a lens that absorbs (rather than transmits) the light of your wavelength. Like IR through glass. It's transmission at wavelength you need to check to see if it will serve as a good lens

Comment: The manufacturers typically provide graphs of the materials they offer

Comment: expanding on gabo_18's answer, recall a glass prism disperses (separates) light at different frequencies; the angle of refraction is different for each color. IR and UV are there too, you just can't see them with your eye, or else they are absorbed by the glass. Same thing happens in a lens

Comment: Light is not amplified by a lens.  It is focused or dispersed, and you'd expect light to be absorbed to some small extent as well.  Amplification would mean more light leaving the lens than entering.  Perhaps the OP might change "amplification" to "deflected" or something similar ?

Comment: @StephenG Thanks for the correction. It's a mistake in the word-choosing that I often make in my native language.

Comment: I think native English speakers (like me) are very careless generally about using the right words, so I for one appreciate the extra effort non-native speakers make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two very concrete answers to this question:

- you can buy IR film (and digital cameras can be converted for IR), and I have used it.  You typically need to adjust focus for IR: good lenses often had IR markings.  So yes, IR is focussed by ordinary camera lenses.
- ordinary photographic film is often mildly sensitive to UV: a standard purchase in the film era was a UV filter, which would reduce haze due from clear skies, which have a lot of UV and would cause what is essentially flare.  This does not show that UV is focussed by ordinary camera lenses, but I believe it us.

So yes, both UV and IR, within some limits (not too far from the visible spectrum) are focussed by mundane lenses.

Answer (score 2):

Basically a lens is a device that refracts light to focus or disperse the light beam. It turns out that refraction of light can be highly frequency dependent, as you can understand for example by looking at the Lorentz model in the context of electromagnetism. The idea is that, if you assume that electrons in your medium behave like objects connected to the nucleus by a spring, you can write down a differential equation for the oscillator and study the frequency spectrum.

So, to answer your question, also IR and UV light is affected by a lens, but in a different way than visible light is, and also in a way that is dependent on the material you use.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was incorrectly phrased at first. While you gave a valid answer, another one come up with the answer to my corrected question.